# O que é, e para que serve um "tick event" em PHP?

Tags: php

Estava olhando algumas funções no PHP.net, e me deparei com uma função chamada [`declare`](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.declare.php), e no exemplo, tem algo assim:

```php
declare(ticks=1);
```

Logo abaixo, tem um outro exemplo:

```php
declare(ticks=1);

// A function called on each tick event
function tick_handler() {
    echo "tick_handler() called\n";
}
register_tick_function('tick_handler');
```

Pelo que entendi, é um método que é chamado toda vez que o valor de uma variável é acessado/alterado. 
Mesmo lendo a documentação, fiquei sem entender exatamente o que esse método faz. Em quais situações ele poderia ser útil? O que é um `tick event`?

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/52192/para-que-serve-a-palavra-chave-declare-no-php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Em quais situações ele poderia ser útil?

Acrescentando à resposta do mlemos, dando exemplos mais concretos...

Os ticks têm alguma utilidade em debugging. Por exemplo, para definir um perfil de utilização de memória (optimização de código ou detectar fugas de memória). Num script intensivo que, por vezes, excede os limites de memória, posso usar esta funcionalidade para de X em X ticks detectar quanta memória esta a ser usada pelo processo.
Também usei em testes em Builds de PHP sem debugging activo, na fase final do desenvolvimento de extensões em C para PHP, para simular break-points no código.

Como esta funcionalidade permite simular "multi-threading", pode ser usada para simular computação em paralelo. Alguns usos referidos podem ser:

1. criar rotinas de verificação de recursos como, por exemplo, se uma conexão se mantém activa.
2. Simular uma Aplicação orientada a eventos (Event Driven Application) simples.

No entanto, como o interpretador pára de executar o código "normal" para executar o tick handler, se o código for muito extenso, pode tornar a applicação muito lenta.

Answer (score 4):

As funções registradas como tick handlers são invocadas depois que o Zend Engine executa um (ou mais) comandos de PHP, não apenas quando variáveis são alteradas.

Isto serve executar tarefas em paralelo emulando uma espécie limitada de multi-tarefa.

Não é uma coisa muito usada porque pode tornar os seus scripts muito lentos, por isso não existem muitas aplicações úteis para esta função.