# Para que serve a palavra-chave Declare no PHP?

Tags: php

Afinal de contas, para que serve a palavra chave `declare` no PHP?

Já vi explicações por aí, inclusive no próprio [Manual do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.declare.php), mas ainda assim não achei muito claro a sua funcionalidade.

Ela pode ser útil para o desenvolvimento?

Exemplo:

```
declare (ticks=1) {
    // todo script aqui
}
```

Comment: Li a documentação e fiquei com mais dúvidas ainda.

Comment: Ele não "declara" nada, não é? Muito esquisito!

Comment: E ainda tem a tal da `register_tick_function` para completar mais ainda a confusão!

Comment: Parece que esse recurso será descontinuado no PHP 7. Mas ainda seria legal saber do que se trata, além de conhecer a motivação por trás da feature. :)

Comment: pelo que entendi, você usa o declare pra definir quantos ticks você vai usar, e depois usa os ticks pra chamar a função... ou algo do genero

Comment: Não sei se é isso @RodrigoBorth, pois `ticks=1` executa 1, porém `ticks=2` não funciona

Comment: realmente eu tava bem enganado, depois de ler bastante e fazer os testes cheguei a uma resposta

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Bem, no manual do PHP temos

> A instrução declare é usado para definir diretivas de execução para um bloco de código.

Mais abaixo temos a seguinte frase

> A seção directive permite que o comportamento do bloco do declare seja definido. Atualmente duas 'directive' são reconhecidas: a 'directive' ticks (...) e a 'directive' encoding (...)

*<strike>Que no caso não explica nada</strike>*

Tudo abaixo disso são explicações de como cada um das `directive` funcionam.

Pela explicação e pelos testes fica muito confuso saber o por que usarmos a `directive ticks` porém pelo que entendi você usa o `declare(ticks=N)` para definir quantas funções você precisa usar para ele printar aquilo que você registrou. Exemplo:

```
function tick_handler(){
   echo "tick_handler() called <br>";
}
//crieu uma função para registrar em um tick

register_tick_function('tick_handler');
//registrei a função no tick

$a = 10;
//atribui um valor para a variavel

declare(ticks=1){
   if ($a > 0) {
       $a += 2;
       print($a.'<br>');
   }
}
```

O exemplo acima vai trazer o seguinte resultado:

```
tick_handler() called  //desaparece caso apague a linha 14
12                     //desaparece caso apague a linha 15
tick_handler() called  //desaparece caso apague a linha 15
tick_handler() called  //desaparece junto dos anterios caso apague o if
tick_handler() called  //sempre são exibidos
tick_handler() called
```

De qual forma a `directive ticks` intrfere no código acima?
Simples, o valor de `ticks` define quantos `ciclos nativos(chamadas do sistema não contam)` precisam ser executados para que a `register_tick_function` seja executada.

Por isso que para cada linha de código apagada se reduz o número de respostas. e aumentando o valor de atribuído a ticks aumenta o número de ciclos necessários para que ele execute a chamada da função registrada.

OBS: Note que se você trazer a linha 9 para dentro do escopo do declare você tera mais uma execução do `register_tick_function`

OBS2: Se você fazer um while infinito e vazio ele irá executar o `register_tick_function` a cada ciclo.

**Qual a utilidade disso?**

Se você está utilizando uma função nativa e não tem noção de como ela é executada pelo PHP você pode usar os `ticks` para saber quantos ciclos elas levaram para serem executadas.

**Vale a pena?**

Acredito que não, podemos usar o microtime para saber o tempo que o servidor leva para processar qualquer coisa sem uma sobrecarga, pois executando uma função a cada `N` ciclos vamos estar aumentando o tempo para se ter uma resposta, deixando ela com uma falha, como você pode ver, a 2 ciclos sendo exibidos mesmo sem nenhuma função ser chamada dentro do escopo do `declare` enão não temos uma precisão de quantos ciclos o realmente está levando para executarmos a nossa função

> **NOTA**
>   Cada statement que o PHP executa (salvo algumas exceções) é um "ciclo nativo"
>   Obrigado @bfavaretto
>
> **NOTA²**
>   Ticks serão retirados no PHP 6.
>   Fonte: [TuxRadar](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/4/21/0)
>
> **NOTA³**
>   O PHP 6 não será mais lançado e não é possivel informar no momento se os Ticks estarão presentes no PHP 7

**E quanto ao `declare(encoding='...')`?**
Não se tem muito o que falar sobre ele. A unica coisa que ele faz é definir o `encoding` da página. Você não consegue usar ele pra definir um `encoding` diferente para uma determinada parte do código(eu iria ficar muito feliz se pudesse) pois quando tenta fazer isso ocorre o seguinte erro: 
`"Encoding declaration pragma must be the very first statement in the script"`

> **OUTRA NOTA** Segundo um comentario no manual do php ele sobrescreve o zend.script_encoding setado no php.ini

Encontrei [essa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27280100/php-declare-encoding) no SO gringo sobre o declare encoding sem resposta ainda.

Comment: Cada *statement* que o PHP executa (salvo algumas exceções) é um "ciclo nativo". Acho [este exemplo, derivado do seu](http://ideone.com/69cwvY), um pouco mais claro: o handler é chamado 4 vezes (uma para cada incremento, e outra para a linha do `}`).

Comment: Eu li em algum lugar que o `declare(ticks)` será retirado da linguagem ou pelo menos será obsoleto. Alguém confirma? Seria interessante então falar do `declare(encoding)` que me parece mais relevante?

Comment: @bigown também li isso em algum lugar, vou só ter certeza sobre o encoding e já complemento a resposta

Comment: Nota. PHP6 não será mais lançado. Não sei se isso será válido para o PHP7

Comment: Rodrigo e @bigown não foi retirado no php7, pelo contrário foi adicionado mais uma diretiva o `strict_types`: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.declare.php

Answer (score 5):

No PHP 7 foi adicionado mais uma diretiva: `strict_types`. Essa sim eu vejo ser bastante útil no desenvolvimento porque ela "desfaz" uma parte da "bagunça" de tipos que o PHP possui, deixando o desenvolvedor um pouco mais no controle da aplicação do que antes.

Considerando a função:

```
function increment(int $x): int
{
    return $x + 1;
}

echo increment('1'); // 2
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/GaseousFeistyNetworks) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/kL2sg1)</sup>

Naturalmente o PHP tenta fazer o *cast* do valor de entrada para o tipo que é esperado; isto é, se chamado `increment('1')`, o PHP iria tratar a *string* como inteiro e retornaria 2 como se nada tivesse acontecido.

Ao utilizar o `declare(strict_types=1)`, você informa ao interpretador que quer trabalhar da forma restrita de tipos, em que o PHP deixará de fazer *casts* mágicos. O mesmo exemplo acima, com o `strict_types` ficaria:

```
declare(strict_types=1);

function increment(int $x): int
{
    return $x + 1;
}

echo increment('1');
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/RareGiddyNlp) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/7dz7Ja)</sup>

Neste caso, seria dado um erro fatal:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to increment() must be of the type integer, string given, called in ...

O mesmo funciona para o tipo de retorno da função que, se definido, deverá ser seguido ou, caso contrário, retornará novamente um erro fatal.

- [PHP 7 - Porque que um método que retorna o tipo primitivo String, não gera erro ao retornar um valor Booleano?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/320943/5878)