# PHP 7 - Porque que um método que retorna o tipo primitivo String, não gera erro ao retornar um valor Booleano?

Tags: php, tipagem, método, php-7

PHP 7 - Porque que um método que retorna o tipo primitivo **String**, não gera erro ao retornar um valor **Booleano**?

```
<?php

class Foo
{
    public function bar() : string
    {
        return true;
    }
}

$Foo = new Foo();
echo $Foo->bar();

?>
```

Saída: 1

https://repl.it/repls/StraightBlondTag

Comment: O retorno é, na verdade, `string(1) "1"`.

Comment: Ia falar isso agora. O PHP converte `true` para `string(1) "1"`

Comment: `true` em PHP retorna `1`, exemplo `echo true;` resultado é 1, a conversão para texto fica "1" foi isso que ele fez! Seu comentário se o echo fosse o valor estiver entre aspas ele retorna o texto diferente da sua pergunta.

Comment: Só pra reforçar mais ainda: O PHP não é uma linguagem fortemente tipada. A tipagem do PHP é bem fraquinha (o que pode causar mais problemas do que ajudar em alguns casos)

Comment: [Relacionado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21508/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-uma-linguagem-de-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-est%C3%A1tica-e-din%C3%A2mica)

Comment: Então pela lógica deveria gerar um erro, mas o PHP converte para String. Isso não é bom porque quebra o sentido de declarar o tipo de retorno nos métodos.

Comment: A sua pergunta é boa realmente @LeandroSciola tem que verificar esse aspecto com toda razão ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Por padrão todo o código em `PHP` tem checagem ***Fraca***, e para habilitar coloque uma linha no topo do arquivo inclusive antes dos `namespace` que vai garantir e checar os tipos de forma rigorosa (checagem **Forte**): (`declare(strict_types = 1);`):

```
<?php

    declare(strict_types = 1); // habilitando checagem forte

    class Foo
    {
        public function bar(): string
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    $Foo = new Foo();
    echo ($Foo->bar());


?>
```

ai ele gera o `erro`:

> `Return value of Foo::bar() must be of the type string, boolean returned`

[Exemplo OnLine](https://repl.it/repls/AusterePleasantDevelopments)

***Referencias:***

- [Strict Types e novos tipos de declaração no PHP 7](https://blog.schoolofnet.com/2016/01/strict-types-e-novos-tipos-de-declaracao-no-php-7/)
- [PHP 7 - Return Type Declarations](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php7/php7_returntype_declarations.htm)

Comment: Que tipo de erro é esse? Fatal, warning, ...

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam ele dá um `PHP Fatal error Uncaught TypeError: Return value of Foo::bar() must be of the type string, boolean returned `

Comment: Pra mim isso deveria ser default e as pessoas teriam que configurar no php.ini para colocar `strict_types = Off` hehehehe

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Mas eles querem fomentar o código quebrado e com bugs, então não dá não! xD

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento concordo, mas isso geraria uma montanha de bugs do core. Veja, por exemplo, [esse bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71053) que eu reportei 3 anos atrás. Um dev não queria aceitar que era um bug do core e queria mudar para um problema de documentação apenas, pois, iria a correção "gerar muitos problemas". Isso acaba "atrasando o progresso".

Comment: @GabrielHeming não é BUG, sim eu entendo os efeitos colaterais, ainda mais em softwares escritos em PHP5, mas é por isso que sugeri existir a flag para desligar. Fora que acho que houve problemas no range do PHP7.0.x do qual eles mesmo emitem notas, justamente por este seu caso talvez não ter sido o unico. No 7.2 não sei como esta o caso especifico. De qualquer forma obrigado por compartilhar.