# Configurar register_tick_function() no xampp

Tags: php

Estou tentando usar a função **register_tick_function()**, mas está travando o meu servidor de desenvolvimento. Mas também não estou conseguindo usar essa mesma função no servidor de produção.

Peço que me ajudem, por favor, a configurar em meu servidor o uso da função **register_tick_function()** e funções semelhantes.

Desde já agradeço!
Galera se não sabe PHP avançado não respondam e nem votem negativo, pois é um tópico avançado.

Comment: Oi, M., não está nada claro se está travando no servidor dev E no prod, ou só em um mas não em outro... O que mostram os logs de erro? Em qual contexto está usando a função?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei como esta o seu código, mas é provavel que você não tenha declarado o `ticks=1`, a documentação em português não apresenta um exemplo correto, conforme a documentação em inglês:

- http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.declare.php#control-structures.declare.ticks
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-tick-function.php#refsect1-function.register-tick-function-examples

Segue um exemplo de uso:

```
<?php
declare(ticks=1);

// A function called on each tick event
function tick_handler()
{
    echo "tick_handler() called\n";
}

register_tick_function('tick_handler');

$a = 1;

if ($a > 0) {
    $a += 2;
    print($a);
}
```

Não recomendo usar em produção. Outro detalhe, é bem improvável, mas se o seu servidor for PHP5.2 isto não irá funcionar se o modulo for "threaded":

> Warning
>   register_tick_function() should not be used with threaded web server modules with PHP 5.2 or lower.

**Relacionados:**

- [O que é, e para que serve um "tick event" em PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3767/3635)
- [Para que serve a palavra-chave Declare no PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52192/3635)